How to store decimal fields defined in MySQL and support range queries in Elasticsearch?
I need to store the decimal type fields defined in MySQL in Elasticsearch without precision loss. My decimal configuration is [db. DECIMAL (21,8)].
I tried to use [ScaledFloat (scaling factor=10 * * 8)] to implement it. But I found that the values stored in Elasticsearch are limited to the minimum or maximum value of the long type. If my value is too large, it will be stored as 9223372036854775807, and when using range query, if the number I query is too large, I will also use 9223372036854775807 to filter.
What should I do?

Store them as strings?

@Chris May I ask, if I choose the first method, how can I perform a range query, such as obtaining all data for prices above 5000984983098.787?

Don't know, but that's one way to preserve arbitrary precision when jamming data into a product that doesn't support it.

method1:
You can Store the decimal values as a type keyword in Elasticsearch. This will preserve the exact string representation without loosing the decimal and loss of precision.
method 2:
split the value into 2 separate fields one for the integer and other for the decimal(fractional part).
method 3:
consider other data type if feasible.
put your indexing:
{
  "mappings": {
      "decimal_field": {
        "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}


May I ask, if I choose the first method, how can I perform a range query, such as obtaining all data for prices above 5000984983098.787?

i am positive we can do. But not 100% confident need to do and verify myself
